# In a POSIX unix system, is it possible to mmap() a file in such a way that it will never be swapped out to disk in favor of other files?

Tags: c, unix, search, mmap

If not using `mmap()`, it seems like there should be a way to give certain files "priority", so that the only time they're swapped out is for page faults trying to bring in, e.g., executing code, or memory that was `malloc()`'d by some process, but never other files. One can think of situations where this could be useful. Consider search engines, which should keep their index files in cache, but which may be simultaneously writing new files (not being used for search).

Comment: If you're interested in this kind of performance tuning, I suggest studying projects like Varnish and PostgreSQL.

Comment: I was under the impression that the way PostgreSQL solved this problem was by creating its own caching layer and doing all file I/O behind the `O_DIRECT` flag, effectively giving the kernel the middle finger. Maybe it's time to start learning kernel development if there's no out-of-the-box solution to this sort of problem I outlined. :)

Comment: That's not necessarily a good solution for your project, it's just a possible solution.  For contrast, look at Varnish, which basically relies on the kernel's memory subsystem to handle caching.  So you can either fight the kernel, or you make the kernel do your work for you.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few ways.

The best way is with `madvise()`, which allows you to inform the kernel that you will need a particular range of memory soon, which gives it priority over other memory.  You can also use it to say that a particular range will not be needed soon, so it should be swapped out sooner.

The hack way is with `mlock()`, which forces a range of memory to stay in RAM.  This is generally not a good idea, and should only be used in special cases.  The most common case is to store passwords in RAM so that the password cannot be recovered from the swap file after the computer is powered off.  I would not use `mlock()` for performance tuning unless I had exhausted other options.

The worst way is to constantly poke memory, forcing it to stay fresh.

Comment: +1 for saying "please pretty please don't do this" :)

Comment: Deleted my answer. This one is better.

Comment: It seems to me that `madvise(WILLNEED)` will simply suggest to the kernel that it start doing readahead on the given chunk of memory. Is there any protection guarantee against getting swapped out in favor of pages in buffer cache?